# Spark No module named found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple spark program and I get the following error -

Error:-

```
ImportError: No module named add_num
```

Command used to run :-

```
./bin/spark-submit /Users/workflow/test_task.py
```

Code:-

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from add_num import add_two_nos

def map_func(x):    
    print(add_two_nos(5))
    return x*x

def main():
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("test-task")\
        .master("local[*]")\
        .getOrCreate()      
    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5]) # parallelize into 2
    rdd = rdd.map(map_func) # call the image_chunk_func 
    print(rdd.collect())    
    spark.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

function code:-

```
def add_two_nos(x):
    return x*x
```

Comment: do you have an `add_num.py` module which includes the function code, as implied from `from add_num import add_two_nos`?

Comment: Yes, It’s there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the .py file form which you wish to import in the code itself by adding a statement `sc.addPyFile(Path)`. 
The path passed can be either a local file, a file in HDFS (or other Hadoop-supported filesystems), or an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP URI.
Then use `from add_num import add_two_nos`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a zip containing add_num.py in your spark-submit command.

```
./bin/spark-submit --py-files sources.zip /Users/workflow/test_task.py
```

When submitting a python application to spark, all the source files imported by the main function/file(here test_task.py) should be packed in a egg or zip format and supplied to spark using --py-files option. If the main function needs only one other file, you can supply it directly without zipping it.

```
./bin/spark-submit --py-files add_num.py /Users/workflow/test_task.py
```

Above command should also work since there is only one other python source file required.